# RadDock change background telerik winforms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, windows-forms-designer

I want change background color for RadDock Telerik control C# WinForms

I want to change blue default background color to white
I tried changing it by all properties in the form not affected ?!

What can I do to change background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
    radDock1.SplitPanelElement.Fill.BackColor = Color.Red;
    radDock1.SplitPanelElement.Fill.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;

    radDock1.MainDocumentContainer.SplitPanelElement.Fill.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    radDock1.MainDocumentContainer.SplitPanelElement.Fill.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;
```

Comment: it`s work correctly thank you, but when create new form then make this form its MdiParent = myMainForm; 
header for the new form display with blue default color, how can i change this color ?

Comment: To customize the floating windows, you should use the FloatingWindowCreated event. Here is how to modify the title bar color:
   void radDock1_FloatingWindowCreated(object sender, FloatingWindowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Window.FormElement.TitleBar.FillPrimitive.BackColor = Color.Red;
            e.Window.FormElement.TitleBar.FillPrimitive.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;
        }